# Below is my inference code for an object detection model. Please tell me what I can add to count the total number of detected images

Tags: python

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):

```
return np.array(Image.open(path))
```

for image_path in img:

```
print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')
image_np=load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
input_tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
input_tensor=input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
detections=detect_fn(input_tensor)
num_detections=int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections={key:value[0,:num_detections].numpy()
               for key,value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections']=num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes']=detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

image_np_with_detections=image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np_with_detections,
      detections['detection_boxes'],
      detections['detection_classes'],
      detections['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      max_boxes_to_draw=100,     
      min_score_thresh=.3,     
      agnostic_mode=False)
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
print('Done')
plt.show()
```

I expect the above output.

Comment: i suppose your refering to this https://gist.github.com/nuzrub/ee3dc19242915278e95cb75014e29083 ... in this case why are you popping `"num_detections"` value? and what is `detect_fn`?

Comment: The code is working fine; all I need is to count the total number of detected images.

Comment: isnt the `num_detections` var the total_num of detected images?